# SQL query Update with Subquery

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

I need to update the column `stock_ID` in `tbl_Item_history`, and the values should be from `stock_ID` of `tbl_Stock_list`. I try to write the query but it does'nt work

```
UPDATE tbl_item_history
SET Stock_ID = (
SELECT tbl_stock_list.Stock_ID as Stock_ID from tbl_item_history, tbl_stock_list
WHERE tbl_item_history.IH_ITEMNO = tbl_stock_list.Stock_Code)
```

It comes with `Subquery returns more than 1 values.....`

Any help would be appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE ih
SET Stock_ID = sl.Stock_ID
FROM tbl_item_history ih
INNER JOIN tbl_stock_list sl
ON ih.IH_ITEMNO = sl.Stock_Code;
```